# How to use S3 docker store for ECS?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, docker-registry

We are using an S3 bucket as docker registry. If we want to use it in an instance or on premise server, we setup registry & then use it. Now, we are moving to ECS. How can we integrate S3 docker store with ECS?

One more question, thought it's irrelevant to the context.
We are using public S3 bucket as registry with following docker command

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY=###aws-access-key### -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY=###aws-secret-key### -e REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION=us-east-1 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=bucket-name -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_CACHE_BLOBDESCRIPTOR=inmemory --name registry registry:2
```

However, If we use it as follows without access-key & secret-key, though it's a public bucket, I wonder why it's not working

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION=us-east-1 -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=bucket-name -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_CACHE_BLOBDESCRIPTOR=inmemory --name registry registry:2
```

Here is my s3 bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken into consideration migration to [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)?
It's far more simple than using S3 as Docker registry and you can also apply lifecycle rules etc.

Anyways using S3 as registry for ECS should be same as using from another source. You just need to make sure your instances will reach it (e.g. create [VPC Endpoint](https://tomgregory.com/when-to-use-an-aws-s3-vpc-endpoint/)).